# The close prices of two currency pairs are not displayed properly when it in a subwindow

Tags: mql5

I want to display the close prices of two currency pairs in a sub-window on the `MT5` chart as custom indicator.

I'm trying to implement it with the code below, but not displayed properly like image below.

How can I display it correctly?

[image]

---

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2023"
#property link ""
#property version "1.00"

#property indicator_separate_window

#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_plots 2

#property indicator_type1 DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1 clrDeepPink

#property indicator_type2 DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color2 clrDarkBlue

double Symbol1Buffer[];
double Symbol2Buffer[];

int OnInit()
{
  SetIndexBuffer(0, Symbol1Buffer, INDICATOR_DATA);
  SetIndexBuffer(1, Symbol2Buffer, INDICATOR_DATA);

  return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
  int to_copy;
  to_copy = rates_total - prev_calculated;

  if (to_copy == 0)
  {
    to_copy++;
  }

  CopyClose("EURUSD", 0, 0, to_copy, Symbol1Buffer);
  CopyClose("GBPUSD", 0, 0, to_copy, Symbol2Buffer);

  return (rates_total);
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
  Print("DeInit");
  return;
}
```

---